# Requiring Sign-In For Shortcode-Based Plugin

Tags: wordpress, redirect, shortcode, wordpress-plugin-creation

Developing a plugin for personal use that adds data-driven content to WordPress pages through shortcodes. In the current implementation, the shortcode php checks if the visitor is authorized (specifically, if the visitor is me), displays the data-driven content if authorized, and displays a message if not.

Instead of a message, I'd like to do an auth_redirect. But by the time my shortcode is parsed, WordPress has already begun sending content to the client, so the redirect doesn't happen.

Is there a (simple) way to get auth_redirect behavior from shortcodes? For instance, can I somehow pass the return URL to the wp-login page? Or do the authorization check earlier in the page processing?

Comment: Have your code return a `<script>` tag with a `window.location` redirection if the current user isn't authorized to view the data.

Comment: you can test the content with [has_shortcode](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/has_shortcode)

Comment: @Kaperto, that may be part of the solution to my question, but your answer is so succinct that I have no idea how to begin implementing.

Comment: @cabrerahector, that may be a way to send my user somewhere else, but it's client-sided redirection, which I'd much prefer not to use. Also, it doesn't address the return to the original page after login.

Answer (score 1):

It's much simpler than I thought: I can simply href to the login page and pass the current page's url as parameter:

```
esc_url(wp_login_url( get_permalink()))
```

Hyperlinking to this sends me to the wp login page, and the get_permalink parameter ensures I return to the calling page after login.